# How to improve scalability when reading a large MongoDB collection in python using pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, lambda, pymongo, bson, aws-documentdb

I am trying to read a large collection in python from MongoDB using pymongo. But My understanding is that this process is not scalable for large datasets.

Is there a way to read the collection as raw BSON which then I can write to S3?

My current code -

```
import json
import pymongo
import urllib
import boto3
from bson import json_util
from datetime import date
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson.json_util import loads

def lambda_handler(event, context):   
    try:
        client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://<username>:"<password><>/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false")
        try:
            db = client["<>"]
            col = db.<collection_name>
            cursor = list(col.find().sort([ ("$natural",1) ]).limit(75000))
            # doc_count = col.count_documents()
        except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure as e:
            return str(e)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
        
    try:
        file_name = "test_" + date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        object = s3.Object(
        bucket_name = "<bucket name>", 
        key=file_name)
        
        for document in cursor:
            object.put(Body=bytes(dumps(document.raw,default=json_util.default).encode('utf-8')))
        
        return ('S3 connection succesful')
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

The current method works perfectly for upto 50,000 documents. But when I set the limit to 75,000, it times out at 10 mins.

From what I understand reading the collection as raw BSON is the way to go?

Comment: Can you add option `{allowDiskUse: true}`? In latest MongoDB version, this became even the default.

Comment: What is your goal or use case here? How often will you run this? Is the timeout coming from lamda? Data is always sent to and from the database in BSON format, it's the responsibility of the drivers to (de)serialize it. It takes time to move data and that time will grow linearly with the size of the data. May wish to pursue alternate approaches instead, but but depends on what/why you are trying to do